# Symfony2 relationship between two entities

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony

I want to make a relationship between two entities but for some reason I am getting NULL on one of the values...

So in my skin entity I have an email_registration_id field with the relationship :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="email_registration_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $email_registration_id;

 /**
     * Set email_registration_id
     *
     * @param \Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email $email_registration_id
     * @return Skin
     */
    public function setEmailRegistrationId(\Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email $email_registration_id = null)
    {
        $this->email_registration_id = $email_registration_id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email_registration_id
     *
     * @return \Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email
     */
    public function getEmailRegistrationId()
    {
        return $this->email_registration_id;
    }
```

And this is the Email entity:

```
    /**
     * Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email
     *
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="email")
     */
    class Email {

        /**
         * @var integer $id
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @var string $title
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
         */
        protected $title;

        /**
         * @var string $registration_content
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="registration_content", type="string")
         */
        protected $registration_content;

        /**
         * @var string $confirmation_apuestas
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="confirmation_apuestas", type="string")
         */
        protected $confirmation_apuestas;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function setId() {
            $this->id = null;
        }

        /**
         * Set title
         *
         * @param string $title
         * @return Email
         */
        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get title
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }

        /**
         * Set registration_content
         *
         * @param string $registration_content
         * @return Email
         */
        public function setRegistrationContent($registration_content)
        {
            $this->registration_content = $registration_content;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get registration_content
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getRegistrationContent()
        {
            return $this->registration_content;
        }

        /**
         * Set $confirmation_apuestas
         *
         * @param string $confirmation_apuestas
         * @return Email
         */
        public function setConfirmationApuestas($confirmation_apuestas)
        {
            $this->confirmation_apuestas = $confirmation_apuestas;

            return $this;
        }

        /**


 * Get $confirmation_apuestas
     *
     *

 @return string
     */
    public function getConfirmationApuestas()
    {
        return $this->confirmation_apuestas;
    }
}
```

Now in my cms i create a new email like this:

```
/**
     * @Route("/new", name="cms_email_new")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction() {
        $item = new Email();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EmailType($this->container->getParameter("langs")), $item);

        return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'item' => $item);
    }
```

The form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option) {
    $builder->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'cms.Title'));

    $builder->add('registration_content', 'textarea', array('label' => 'cms.registration.content'));

    $builder->add('confirmation_apuestas', 'textarea', array('label' => 'cms.confirmation.apuestas'));
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email',
    );
}
```

This is how I persist the Email to the database:

```
/**
     * @Route("/save", name="cms_email_save")
     * @Template("ProjectUserBundle:EmailAdmin:new.html.twig")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */
    public function saveAction(Request $request) {

        $item = new Email();
        $type = new EmailType($this->container->getParameter("langs"));
        $form = $this->createForm($type, $item);
        $form->bind($request);
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $this->upload($form, $item);

            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cms_skin_email_list', array('skin_id' => $item->getId())));
        }

        return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'item' => $item);
    }
```

The problem is that it creates an email, but in my skin entity, the email_registration_id is just NULL and not the same as emails Id... Maybe I missed something?

UPDATE

So this is what I made according to the responses I got:

class Email {

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin", mappedBy="email_registration_id")
 */
protected $skin;

/**
     * Set skin
     *
     * @param string $skin
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setSkin(\Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin $skin = null)
    {
        $this->skin = $skin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get skin
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSkin()
    {
        return $this->skin;
    }
```

And the form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option) {
        $builder->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'cms.Title'));

        $builder->add('registration_content', 'textarea', array('label' => 'cms.registration.content'));

        $builder->add('confirmation_apuestas', 'textarea', array('label' => 'cms.confirmation.apuestas'));

        $builder->add('skin', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'ProjectSkinBundle:Skin',
            'property' => 'id',
        ));
    }
```

However when i am trying to flush to the database I get this error:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\Company\front\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 528 and defined in C:\wamp\www\Company\front\vendor\doctrine\collections\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.php line 48
```

Comment: `$this->product1 = $email_registration_id;` Why are you assigning the value to `product1` property?

Comment: @Artamiel you are right I missed that line! But it didnt fix my problem..

Comment: Could you please include your code where you actually persist and save the data to your database. Since you've shown code about `Email`, but your problem is actually about setting a relationship value to your `Skin` entity.

Comment: Yup, right now all you do is creating new `Email` and that's it. You either have to create new `Skin` entity and manually call `->setEmailRegistrationId($item);` if your form is correctly validated, or take a look at @Guillaume Fache answer.

Comment: @Artamiel Can you ckeck my post again? I am getting some errors

Comment: Have you added the "inversedBy" to your ManyToOne annotation ? More generaly, you can use the debug bar at the bottom of your page, to see what entities have problem, and what the problem is. It's a very useful tool, don't hesitate to add its log when needed.

Comment: The problem is that he is using `OneToMany` relation with `Email`<->`Skin` and trying to set singe entity object to the collection. The form mapping is incorect right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal that the creation of a new email is not associated to a skin object. How could it ? The relation is unidirectional, and only works when you create a skin and you give it an email. To create an email and give it a skin, you have to make the relation bidirectional, and add it to your email form.

To do this, I'd do the following :

```
/*
* Class Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email
*/
class Email {
    ...
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin", mappedBy="email_registration_id")
*/
protected $skin;
```

and in your form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option) {
$builder->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'cms.Title'))
        ->add('registration_content', 'textarea', array('label' => 'cms.registration.content'))
        ->add('confirmation_apuestas', 'textarea', array('label' => 'cms.confirmation.apuestas'))
        ->add('skin')
        ;
}
```

And PS : You should not use the bind() method to handle the request, it is deprecated. Instead use :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

UPDATE 1 : Don't forget to also update your ManyToOne annotation adding the inversedBy part :

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email", inversedBy="skin")
```

And also, of course, update your database.